# azure websites redirect to https regardless of ssl binding

Tags: azure

I have an Azure Website with a custom domain and an SNI SSL binding and am running into an issue where all my subdomains are redirecting to SSL even though the binding is only configured to www.mydomain.com.

There are a couple of subdomains (ex: docs.mydomain.com) that are actually CNAMES to external resources that do not support HTTPS and therefore, they have to be linked over plain HTTP. Unfortunately, whenever I type in docs.mydomain.com, it redirects to HTTPS.

As previously mentioned, the SSL binding is only to www.mydomain.com.

Is there a trick to making this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Chrome was strangely caching the SSL state. Re-installing Chrome fixed the issue.

Comment: Any chance you ever had an HSTS header on your domain?

Comment: @Frans this would be at the server-level, correct? My app service is running the Wordpress template from the Azure marketplace. That said, I didn't add anything to enable HSTS. The confusing part was that it was redirecting to HTTPS on CNAMEs.